# How do you use CONCAT within a JSON path for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, path

**MySQL Version 5.7**

Given that h.`ent_rollup` length is always >=4 and I want to get the second to the last array element in a JSON data field that only holds a single array:

Example JSON value for `ent_rollup`:

```
["15","26","57","28","89","10","11","12"]
```

Example: I want this

```
SELECT h.`ent_rollup`->>CONCAT('"$[',(JSON_LENGTH(h.`ent_rollup`))-2,']"') FROM hierarchy h
```

to translate to this

```
SELECT h.`ent_rollup`->>"$[6]" FROM hierarchy h
```

I want to get `11` back but I'm getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'concat('"$[', 
(json_length(h.`ent_rollup`))-2,']"') from hierarchy h
where h.`en' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `->>` the path has to be a literal expression (although the documentation doesn't say so explicitly). If you want to calculate the path, use the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function.

You also have extra `"` characters in the path, which cause MySQL to fail (when I try it on rextester.com it times out waiting for the response).

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(h.ent_rollup, CONCAT('$[',JSON_LENGTH(h.ent_rollup)-2,']'))) 
FROM hierarchy h;
```

Comment: That works, thanks! The extra quotes was to ensure the concat function wrapped everything in double quotes.

Comment: Those quotes are part of source code syntax, they're not part of the string itself.